# Is there a way to show html source in the browser after insertion by js?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser

Is there a way to show html source in the browser after insertion by js via  `~.innerHTML = Source;`  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working with Firebug/Firefox or with IE8, the DOM viewer can show you the "live" DOM.  It's not really "source", but I'm pretty sure that's what you're asking about.

(I didn't mention Safari or Chrome because I don't do much development with those, but they probably have similar facilities. I'm just not personally familiar.)

Comment: Safari and Chrome has a built-in HTML/JS/DOM degubber like IE8, so we could say that it's implemenetd in every major navigator :)

Answer (score 1):

The WebDeveloper add-on for Firefox among its many useful features also has a 'View Generated Source' feature that works just like view source, but includes the dynamic content.  Simple and quick.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/

Answer (score 0):

Pure Firefox without any plugins:
select code with mouse -> right-click -> "View Selection Source"